# Why is my String to String comparison failing?

Tags: java, android, string

I have an Android app where I want to check to see if an app name that is installed matches a string passed to the function containing this code. The code and example is below:

```
private Boolean checkInstalledApp(String appName){
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager(); 
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null); 
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 
    List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    Boolean isInstalled = false;
    for(ResolveInfo info: list) {
      if (info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel( pm ).toString()==appName){
          isInstalled = true;
          break;  
      }
    } 

    return isInstalled;
}
```

Assuming you called `checkInstalledApp("SetCPU");` and the app name on the phone is called the same thing it should return `true`. However, it never does. I logged the results and it should match up but it does not. Can anyone please enlighten me as to why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the String's equals() method instead of the == operator for comparing strings:

```
info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel( pm ).toString().equals(appName)
```

In Java, one of the most common mistakes newcomers meet is using `==` to compare Strings. You have to remember, `==` compares the object references, not the content.

Comment: Ah I see. That is definitely a mistake this newcomer made. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Check out number 7: [Top 10 - New Java Developer Errors](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Eton had already sufficiently answered the question, I was giving extra information. Perhaps it should have been a comment

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean compaireString (String string, String string2) 
{
    // string == null && String2 == null or they reference the same object
    if (string == string2) return true;
    //we have to be sure that string is not null before calling a methode on it
    if (string != null && string.equals(string2)) return true;

   return false;
}
```