# String Value not working in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my string to string comparison failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576413/why-is-my-string-to-string-comparison-failing)

I am unable to store assign a value to string variable , I have given my program below

```
 public class MahindraActivity extends Activity {
    EditText userid,pwd1;
    Button loginbut;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    Connection con;
    String userrole1;
    //String userid1,pass1;
    String url="jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://10.0.2.2:1433;DatabaseName=swingmail";
    String user="sa";
    String pwd="sa";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mahindra);
        userid=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
       //String userid1=userid.getText().toString();
        pwd1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        //String pass1=pwd1.getText().toString();
        loginbut=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        loginbut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(MahindraActivity.this, "Please Wait"+userid.getText().toString(), 10).show();
                login(userid.getText().toString(),pwd1.getText().toString());
            }

            private void login(String userid1, String pass1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
                    con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
                    st=con.createStatement();
                    String str="select userrole from usermaster where m_loginid='"+userid1+"'and m_password='"+pass1+"'" ;
                    rs= st.executeQuery(str);
                    while(rs.next()){
                    userrole1=rs.getString("userrole");
                    if(userrole1=="admin"){
                        Intent intent=new Intent(MahindraActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_mahindra, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

When Debugging the project value for userrole is giving "admin" from the table but when assigning it to string variable `String userrole1` it gives null at the line

```
while(rs.next()){
                    userrole1=rs.getString("userrole");
                    if(userrole1=="admin"){
                        Intent intent=new Intent(MahindraActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

If loop is skipped and goes to the catch part, Can some one please explain the reason or spot out the error

Comment: 1. add your logcat output.
2. In java String can not be complete using "==" instead use String.equals method.

Comment: check your logcat by writing Log.d("log","my output===>"+rs.getString("userrole"));

Comment: while(rs.next()){
                    userrole1=rs.getString("userrole"); Log.d("log","my output===>"+rs.getString("userrole"));                      
                    if(userrole1=="admin"){
                        Intent intent=new Intent(MahindraActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

Comment: checked it returns the value as "admin" but iam not able to store it in the variable userrole1

Comment: You mean "rs.getString("userrole");" returns null?

Comment: asign the String userrole1="";

Comment: rs.getString("userrole") have value admin but  in userrole1=rs.getString("userrole"); userrole1 has null value when debugging it

Comment: @VivekShankar Please see my answer and if you have any issue then tell me or if my answer is helping you then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void login(String userid1, String pass1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String userrole1 = "";
                try{

                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
                    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
                    Statement st=con.createStatement();
                    String str="select userrole from usermaster where m_loginid='"+userid1+"'and m_password='"+pass1+"'" ;
                    ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(str);
                    while(rs.next()){
                    userrole1=rs.getString(1);
                    }

                    if(userrole1.equals("admin")){
                        Intent intent=new Intent(MahindraActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

i simply added the String Userrole1 inside the method and hence works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
userrole1.equals("admin");
```

Comment: iam unable to assign the value from rs.getString("userrole") to String variable userrole1

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare string with `== operator` . You have to use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` method of String class.

Try this.

```
if(userrole1.equalsIgnoreCase("admin"))
{
    Intent intent=new Intent(MahindraActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

> `equalsIgnoreCase` returns true if the two String objects contain
>   either exactly the same data or if they differ only in case; false
>   otherwise.

Comment: Answer Solver declared the variable String userrole1 inside the login() method and now works fine

Comment: @VivekShankar Do not Forget to accept answer which solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Write below code

```
if(userrole1.equals("admin")){
    Intent intent=new Intent(MahindraActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

instead of

```
if(userrole1=="admin"){
    Intent intent=new Intent(MahindraActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And Declare String userrole1 into login() method, it will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks i corrected the if loop but iam unable to assign rs.getString("userrole") to String variable userrole1

Comment: @VivekShankar which error do you getting?, post here

Comment: String userrole is stored with null

Comment: @VivekShankar Create userrole1 variable in while loop only.

Comment: Answer Solver declared the variable String userrole1 inside the login() method and now works fine

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct that you should not be using the `==` operator, but they will not fix your issue.  If the result of `rs.getString("userrole")` is `null`, then this is assigned to a variable and you perform

```
if(userrole1.equals("admin")){
```

this will throw a `NullPointerException` as `userrole1` is `null`.  Instead, reverse the comparison:

```
if("admin".equals(userrole1)){
```

This will return `false` if `userrole1` is `null`, rather than falling over.

Comment: rs.getString("userrole") have value admin but in userrole1=rs.getString("userrole"); userrole1 has null value when debugging it

Comment: How, exactly, do you know that userrole1 is `null`?  Please edit your question to include the code you used to debug it and the corresponding log output.  Have you changed your `if` test in the way I outlined?  Also, add a `break;` statement after the call to `startActivity`.  If `rs.getString("userrole")` returns `admin` then you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: BECAUSE WHILE DEBUGGING and watching specific rs.getString(1) shows admin as value but after assigning to userrole1 the userrole1 shows null in debug window

Comment: There are many ways to debug a program.  Running the application in debug mode and stepping through one line at a time, writing data out to files, printing variables to logcat etc.  Please state EXACTLY how you are "debugging" it.  Preferably you are writing the variable out to the log.  If so, edit your question to include the code you are using for debugging, along with the logcat output it produces.